# Does usage of Thread.Sleep(n) causes performance issues?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using Thread.Sleep(n) for my project. I heard that Thread.Sleep can cause performance issues but not sure about it.

My requirement is:

> Wait for 5 minute increments, up to 30 minutes (6 times the 5 minute
>   delay).  After this, begin to increment by 1 hour and do this 5 times
>   (additional 5 hours).

Below I have provided my sample code which uses Thread.Sleep(n) in different scenarios:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 5); //-------waiting for 5 minutes
var isDownloaded = false;
try
{
    var attempt = 0;
    while (attempt < 11)
    {
        isDownloaded = TryDownloading(strPathToDownload, strFileToDownload);
        if (isDownloaded)
            break;
        attempt++;
        if (attempt < 6)
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 5); //--------waiting for 5 minutes
        else
        {
            if (attempt < 11)
                Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60); //-------waiting for 1 hour
            else
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

On the above code I am trying to download a file with a maximum of 11 download attempts. Initially it waits for 5 minutes and then try to download the file which is the *first attempt* and if failed then it tries for the **next 5 attempts with an interval of 5 minutes each**. If they failed for the first six attempts then it go for the **next 5 attempts with an interval for 1 hour each**.

So we decided to use Thread.Sleep for those time delay in our console app.

Does this causes any problem or performance issues?

If Thread.Sleep(n) causes performance issues, then which would be an better alternative way instead of using Thread.Sleep(n)?

Also finally, Does MSDN suggested that Thread.Sleep(n) is harmful or it shouldn't be used?

Comment: It's harmfull, because you can't abort it. And it will use threads from pool that processes web application requests

Comment: It sounds like you should have a separate process, and use the OS to schedule it.

Comment: There was no indication of how ASP.NET is involved, so I removed references to it. If you are using ASP.NET somewhere in your system, you should indicate how it matters.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov we are not using the web app, it's a console app. We manually run it, when it is needed.

Comment: why then you added asp.net tag?

Comment: Would you hire someone to do a job and then pay them to sleep?  This sounds like a job for a timer or some other scheduling mechanism.

Comment: @EricLippert I think using Timer will be a good option, what about your suggestion?

Answer (score 11):

This is absolutely fine. Here are the costs of sleeping:

- You keep a thread occupied. This takes a little memory.
- Setting up the wait inside of the OS. That is `O(1)`. The duration of the sleep does not matter. It is a small, constant cost.

That's all.

What is bad, though, is busy waiting or doing polling loops because that causes actual CPU usage. Just spending time in a sleep or wait does not create CPU usage.

TL;DR: Use sleep for delays, do not use sleep for polling.

I must say that the aversion against sleeping is sometimes just a trained reflex. Be sure to analyze the concrete use case before you condemn sleeping.

Comment: It's the sleep syllogism: "Sleep calls are used for inter-thread polling loops.  Inter-thread comms polling loops are bad because of CPU/memory-bandwith waste and avoidable latency. SO, sleep is bad and must never be used'.  This twaddle has been repeated so many times that developers believe it.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not use ASP.NET worker process to run long running tasks!**

The app pool may be recycled any time and you will lose your sleeping threads.

Consider using Windows Service instead.
You can communicate between web site and windows service using database or messaging.

Comment: Although this is true, he does say: "So we decided to use Thread.Sleep for those time delay in our **console app**." (My emphasis).

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use a Timer to perform intermittent action like that because Thread.Sleep is a blocking call and keeps the process allocated and the application freeze.

like this:
in the caller object

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000 * 60 * 5);
t.Tick += t_Tick;
t.Start();
```

than implement the event

```
//event timer elapsed implementation
int count = 0;
 private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if(count >=5)
  t.Stop();
  else{
  //your code that do the work here
  }
```

Comment: NO it does not.  Thread.Sleep does NOT freeze applications, it blocks the calling THREAD for the interval specified.  Sure, inappropriate use of such blocking calls in a thread that should be handling GUI messages will cause GUI to stop, but the OP comments that he/she is developing a console app and, anyway, just becasue an app has a GUI does not mean it only has one thread - an app with a GUI interface may have other threads where a delay is specified.

Comment: Sure, if you call Sleep in the main ui thread the application freeze. Othervise not.